# How to parse the key value data using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, jython

I want to parse the value from rest response using python

i tried pull the data as a key value pair , but it doesnt like it.

I want to parse the value field data

```
"""[{'name': u'id', 'value': u'000000471687 \n000000471688 \n000000471689 \n'}]"""
```

The actual output needed is:

```
tasks = 000000471687, 000000471688, 000000471689
```

Comment: To be clear, do you want tasks as a single string or a list of strings (or something else)? I ask because your present  "needed output" line will throw a syntax error if you try to assign three variables to a single name like you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it by the following way:

```py
data = """[{'name': u'id', 'value': u'000000471687 \n000000471688 \n000000471689 \n'}]"""

data=eval(data.replace("\n'","'").replace('\n',','))

tasks = ','.join([ str(s).strip() for i in data for s in i['value'].split(',')])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  how to do it for the below data                                     
 data = """[{'name': u'id', 'value': u'000000471687 \n000000471688 \n000000471689 \n'}]"""    -- it is complaining string indices must be integers